# Bootstrap Lining up Row Widths

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a basic layout with a hero image with text overlayed and then 3 columns below. Why won't my margin line up with the main hero image? I'm using a fluid container but everything I've tried, I can't get them to line up to be full width.

I understand that the Row class has a -15px for margin left and right. Then the container has a 15px margin left and right, this should cancel one another out to be 0.

I'm not sure if it's possible but I need the 3 columns to be spaced evenly so there isn't anything butting up against one another but remain full width of the viewport.

Link to fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b4f3fbh5/

`.nav .col-sm-4 {
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }`

Comment: Are you looking for https://jsfiddle.net/b4f3fbh5/4/  .... You need to add media query for removing & adding padding for 2nd & 3rd div container.

Comment: yes! Thank you! I was trying to get everything to span across the entire viewport. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Shiladitya The only thing I can't get quite right is for the 3 columns to have the correct padding of 10px. The first one looks like it has slightly 1 or 2 more pixels.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please specify height for the image tags, it will fix the column 2 & 3 height issue.